# iText7 : Image in pdf file causing error in deferred signing

Tags: java-11, itext7

So I have added a image to pdf. But when I sign the pdf file with image using deferred signing, it's giving the error **"The document has been altered or corrupted since the Signature was applied"** in adobe reader. Removing the image solves this issue.

I have tried different images, different formats(png & jpg), different solutions([solution1](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/examples/png-image-handling) & [solution2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67161143/itext-7-pdf-adding-image-to-document-is-not-flushed-to-disk-but-stays-in-memor)). But the only solution that works is the removal of image?

Here is the implementation I tried to insert image (pre solution1 & solution2 code) :

```
Image pdfImg = new Image(ImageDataFactory.create("src/main/resources/image.png"));
pdfImg.setWidth(defaultPageSize.getWidth() / 4);
pdfImg.setHeight(defaultPageSize.getWidth() / 8);
pdfImg.setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER); 
Document.add(pdfImg);
```

The image I am trying to add is [this](https://abdm.gov.in/assets/images/ndhm-logos.png).

Is there any solution to this?

**Edit 1 :**

As requested here is a [nonSigned](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13i1o9XHe-Wc9gDIp44e8uTisGMCrOCCq/view?usp=drivesdk) pdf and a [signed](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1txStfPNZHCc4fdsMcUJqYtwJsMCOmtR7/view?usp=drivesdk) pdf.

Comment: Can you share the PDFs in question?

Comment: Could you try this? https://www.tutorialspoint.com/itext/itext_adding_image_to_pdf.htm

Comment: Hi @mkl, I have shared the pdfs. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @NikitaKovaliov, in my example above, I am using the same way as mentioned in the tutorial.

Comment: @SirNoobALot, How did you sign the PDF? Through iText or directly in Acrobat? If through iText, can you share the code? If through Acrobat, did you see this topic? https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-discussions/the-document-has-been-altered-or-corrupted-since-the-signature-was-applied/td-p/9353946

Answer (score 0):

The signature indeed is incorrect.

Apparently an issue occurred while calculating the document hash. The embedded signature claims the hash of the signed byte ranges of the PDF is

```
170856708123EFDC173693BB0582FAED1CA8A40D37EA26902E0CC1142EC62F72
```

but it actually is

```
7A767EDF7BA9112A11678E70285E22170595341F8A18F8A9CD7F20AC50296CEF
```

Thus, Adobe Acrobat has reason to assume an alteration or corruption.

---

As an aside, there also appear to be issues in your certificate path.